# Ошибка при установке модуля autopy Python 3.11

Tags: python-3.11

Вот ошибка при установке модуля.

```
dmitry@air-dmitry ~ % pip install autopy
Collecting autopy
  Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/m5/bz_6fkr10bzb57m863t3yw200000gn/T/pip-build-env-tsc6t006/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/m5/bz_6fkr10bzb57m863t3yw200000gn/T/pip-build-env-tsc6t006/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/m5/bz_6fkr10bzb57m863t3yw200000gn/T/pip-build-env-tsc6t006/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/m5/bz_6fkr10bzb57m863t3yw200000gn/T/pip-build-env-tsc6t006/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Хоть и пишет что модуля нет но он есть.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
```